# How to select the value of animation-iteration-count using css or js?

Tags: javascript, css

How can i select the value of animation-iteration-count using js or css ? Below is my css. The aim is first time draw the black color and second time drawred. Thanks for the help.

```
.path { animation: draw 8.5s linear ; } @keyframes draw { 0% {stroke: #000;} 25% {stroke:#000;} 50% {stroke: #000;} 75% {stroke: #000;} 100% {stroke: none;fill:#000;stroke-dashoffset:100; } }
```

Comment: .path {
  animation: draw 8.5s linear ;  
}
  @keyframes draw {
  0%   {stroke: #000;}
      25%  {stroke:#000;}
    50%  {stroke: #000;}
    75%  {stroke: #000;}
    100% {stroke: none;fill:#000;stroke-dashoffset:100; }
}

Comment: Hi, I created a sample fiddle what i have. https://jsfiddle.net/6fyg1msL/1/. I want to give different color in each loop of the animation, now its color is changing in same loop. I want to make it each color for each loop of the animation repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I can do with below jQuery function.

```
 function animate(count) {
            console.log("animate", count)

            if (count == 0) {
                $('.path').css({
                    'animation': 'draw2 4s'
                });

            }

            if (count == 1) {
                $('.path').css({
                    'animation': 'draw1 4s'
                });
            }
            if (count == 2) {
                $('.path').css({
                    'animation': 'draw3 4s'
                });
            }
            if (count > 0) $('.path:first').one("animationend", function () {
                animate(count - 1)
            })
        }
```

Comment: So you completed your task with this?

Comment: No, I want to make the animate function repeat infinite times, how can i do it ? any clue ?